# Jquery chosen: size of select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm using the [jQuery chosen plugin][1] with a search dropdown and i want to set the number of displayed options in the scroll bar to only 2. but it displays 10 options instead. Any idea ?

Jquery:

> $(".select").chosen();

i set the attribute size to 2 in the select tag but nothing happened

```
 <select data-placeholder="Choisir équipe..." class="select" name="Equipe_sup" id="Equipe_sup" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2" size="2"></select>
```

Comment: Shows us your code. The HTML before you run chosen on it. Where you are setting the size to 2, etc.

Comment: If you only want two options to be displayed in the drop down, you should only populate it with two options and not ten. I don't believe it's the drop down list's job to limit the number of selection options for you.

Comment: @Jason Towne: Chosen Jquery plugin is used to display a select list with a y scroll bar which mean i can put any number of options i want. Now in my case i don't want to display more than 2 options at once. http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: I want to set the number of displayed options in the scroll bar to only 2. but it displays 10 options instead // Remove the other options and have only 2 options.

Answer (score 1):

use max-height feature of your element to cap the limit of display element in chosen drop-down

```
$('#id').css("max-height","127px"); // this will display 5 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution use the `size="2"` in your `<select id="select" name="name" title="test" size="2">test</select>`
and try this http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Didn't work ! i'm already using Chosen Jquery and i tried the size attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use this code i hope will be success :

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "100%"});
```